# Bigger (or custom) bullet in password field for Android

Tags: android, fonts

I have an `EditText` that has passwordInput. What I am trying to achieve is to set up a bigger symbol for password dot. Input textSize attribute is 18sp (and it should stay that way, e.g. I don't want to change the text size itself), and I want the bullet to be 22 sp. What I have tried is:

To override transformation with big circle symbol:

```
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        PasswordTransformationMethod mt = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance();
        Field dotField;
        try {
            dotField = PasswordTransformationMethod.class.getDeclaredField("DOT");
            dotField.setAccessible(true);
            dotField.set(null,'\u2b24'); // big circle.. not found in android fonts, uh-oh.
            return mt.getTransformation(source,view);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return super.getTransformation(source,view);
        }
    }
```

However, the symbol in question is missing from Android fonts.

To work around this problem, I've tried to set up a custom SpannableFactory for the edittext:

```
@Override
    public Spannable newSpannable(CharSequence src) {
        String masked = "", unmasked = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {
            if (src.charAt(i) == DOT) {
                masked += src.charAt(i);
            } else {
                unmasked += src.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        debug("Masked: "+ masked+ "; unmasked: " + unmasked);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(masked + unmasked);
        Typeface customFont = null;
        try {
            customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (customFont != null) {
            ssb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(customFont),
                    0, masked.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            );
        }
        return ssb;
  }
```

but this does not seem to work (debug() calls are ignored, so I assume that this code never gets executed), so I didn't try to set StyleSpan instead for buffing up text size w/o changing symbol.

The font itself is there, and is loaded, and I can set it up for the EditText, but if I do so, obviously input typeface is changed as well, which is a no-no.

TL;DR:

Are there any ways to set up a custom font for a portion of text of EditText, or to add a font with missing-by-default-symbols, while keeping original font for other symbols, or to buff up the size of Dots in password inputs?

Comment: What happens if you don't do the things you show, but you tell the passwordInput that its font size is literally 22 instead of 18? The EditText is just a TextView so,,, have you tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize ?

Comment: if I set it to be size 22, then the input text itself is size 22, too. Which is a problem, since I want to achieve 18sp text/22sp dot. Editing the question to reflect it better.

Comment: Serious question: *why* do you want the same base text but bigger password "dots"? Android's text fields all look the same, so users don't get a different look in every app, which makes their lives a lot easier. What benefit does "bigger dots" give? (e.g. it sounds like spending time on breaking the Android style guide rather than developing cool features for your app =)

Comment: The client that gave me the design commented on this, asking me to make the dots bigger.

Comment: usually worth pointing out to clients when they ask for things that don't fit the Android style guide.

Comment: Well, just wanted to make sure that this is either impossible or would take too much time. Thanks for replies, anyways.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Hi. Any solution found?